# More efficient than an if statement?

Tags: php

I'm making a game in PHP (don't ask lol), and the player has a location which is an integer. There's a travel page and this basically shows a 5x5 tiled map. Each tile is a different part of the player's universe. By clicking on it he can travel there.
Just to give you an idea of the integers behind the map:

- 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
- 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
- 31, 32, 33, 34, 35
- 41, 42, 43, 44, 45
- 51, 52, 53, 54, 55

Let's say the player starts at 33(the middle) and I wanted to charge him different rates depending on how far he traveled. So, for example, 1 tile in any direction is a 100 credits, 2 tiles is 200 and so on.

So what I came up with is this. `$ol` represents the player's current location and `$nl` is where they are travelling to...

```
if($ol-11==$nl || $ol-10==$nl || $ol-9==$nl || $ol+1==$nl || $ol+11==$nl || $ol+10==$nl || $ol+9==$nl || $ol-1==$nl || $ol-11==$nl ){
echo "cost 100 credits!";
}
else if($ol-22==$nl || $ol-21==$nl || $ol-20==$nl || $ol-19==$nl || $ol-18==$nl || $ol-8==$nl || $ol+2==$nl || $ol+12==$nl || $ol+22==$nl 

|| $ol+21==$nl || $ol+20==$nl || $ol+19==$nl || $ol+18==$nl || $ol+8==$nl || $ol-2==$nl || $ol-12==$nl ){
echo "cost 200 credits!";
}
```

That's the code for 1 and 2 tile travel. As you can see it's a lengthy statement.

I basically worked out a pattern for the grid I'd set up. For example, travelling up 1 tile would always be -10 of the current tile.

Before I type out any more ridiculously long if statements, is there a neater or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: what about our good old friends `<`, `<=`, `>=` and `>`. They would shorten your if statements a good part.

Comment: Do you allow travel in the diagonal directions, or only along the horizontal or vertical; if the former, is this costed the same as for horizontal/vertical?

Comment: I might renumber the cells with a 0/0 centre point, to allow use of atan2()

Comment: @Horen: Really? Would you mind showing me how?

@ Mark Baker: And yes diagonal travel is allowed. This is the first I've heard of atan2 lol I'll look into it now.

Comment: So if I am at 15 and go to 44, what is the "distance" travelled? Suppose I went from 15 to 43. In each case there is no direct diagonal route?

Comment: Think of the travel system as a square of the player's current position. 44 from 15 is in the 3rd row  diagonally so it would be grouped with 12,22,32,42,43 and 45. If that makes any sense lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a different method: As the first digit defines the row and the second digit the column, I would split the number in these two digits and use these numbers to determine how many rows and how many columns are being travelled.

So for any position:

```
$row = floor($tile_value / 10);
$column = $tile_value % 10;
```

With this it is easy to calculate distances.

**Edit:** A small example to measure absolute distances:

```
$row_org = floor($tile_org_value / 10);
$column_org = $tile_org_value % 10;

$row_new = floor($tile_new_value / 10);
$column_new = $tile_new_value % 10;

$row_diff = $row_new - $row_org;
$col_diff = $col_new - $col_org;

$distance = sqrt(pow($row_diff, 2) + pow($col_diff, 2));
```

Comment: Hmm I think I get what you mean... Would you mind elaborating on this?

Comment: @kidshenlong See my edit to determine the distance travelled using Pythagoras.

Comment: Ahhhh Pythagoras hmmmm I see what @Captain Payalytic was getting at now. Although if I travel from from any tile to a tile in the same vertical row it always returns as 0. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @kidshenlong Then there is a mistake somewhere in the code: the square root of `1^2 + 0^2` is `1`. You should check all variable values along the way if you cannot find it.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me figure out what's going wrong. I even removed the absolute number part to match it to your edits but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: @kidshenlong You should post an example with var_dumps of all variables along the way. That should make it pretty easy to spot what is off / wrong.

Comment: So I stepped away, grabbed a bite to eat and printed out all the variables... Oh man I hate loosely typed languages! Thanks for all your help Jeroen!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably try an array for coordinates. This will allow you to set the initial coordinates. You can then pass new coordinates to the function which will move the position and calculate the cost.

```
<?php

$array = array( );

//populate the array with 0's
for( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++ ) {
    for( $j = 1; $j <= 5; $j++ ) {
        $array[$i][$j] = 0;
    }
}

//set beginning position
$array[3][3] = 1;

function newPosition( $array, $newX, $newY ) {
    $oldX = 0;
    $oldY = 0;

    //locate current position
    foreach($array as $key=>$subArray) {
        foreach($subArray as $subKey=>$val) {
            if($val === 1) {
                $oldX = $key;
                $oldY = $subKey;
            }
        }
    }

    //delete old position
    $array[$oldX][$oldY] = 0;

    //set new position
    $array[$newX][$newY] = 1;

    //Calculate x and y difference
    $xTravel = abs($oldX - $newX);
    $yTravel = abs($oldY - $newY);

    //Add x and y difference
    $totalTravel = $xTravel + $yTravel;

    //Calculate the cost
    $totalCost = $totalTravel * 100;

    echo "cost $totalCost credits!\n";

    return $array;
}

$array = newPosition( $array, 5, 2 );
$array = newPosition( $array, 1, 5 );
$array = newPosition( $array, 1, 5 );
$array = newPosition( $array, 3, 3 );
```

**Output**

```
cost 300 credits!
cost 700 credits!
cost 0 credits!
cost 400 credits!
```

[See the demo](http://codepad.org/sIpjDeQH)

Comment: Thank you for going to the effort of clearly laying this out for me. I'm looking into it right now! :)

Answer (score 1):

As in my comment above, you cannot measure distance in units, since not all points can be reached in a straight line through points.

You need to consider these points to be points (x, y coordinates) on a graph. Then you can get the distance between any 2 points using Pythagoras.

For example, if we consider your top row as being the coordinates (1,1) (1,2) and so on, if the person travels from (1,1) to (4,3), the distance travelled is the square root of 3 (4-1) squared plus 2 (3-1) squared, i.e. sqrt(9+4) = sqrt(13)

Comment: I'm sorry I was never the strongest at maths! But I didn't really want to measure the distances that accurately. I really just wanted to measure it in terms of tiles distance. So like I said above if you were in 15 and wanted to travel to 44, yo'd just go down or across until you hit the same row as the number. So for 44 it'd be in the same travel band as 12,22,32,42,43 and 45 so would cost the same price. If that makes any sense...

Comment: My mistake! This does exactly that. Maths have never been my strong point unfortunately. I'm discussing it further above with @Aarolama Bluenk. Thank you for our contribution :)

Answer (score -2):

Your code seems legit. You could order the conditions so that the most used ones are first.